# OOP and jQuery: how to init a var with Deferred();

Tags: javascript, oop, jquery-deferred

This is my javascript code
Its goal is only for education. I'm studying js OOP and jquery

```
function App() {

this.deviceReadyDeferred = new $.Deferred();

this.init = function() {
    console.log ("Run");
    $.when(this.deviceReadyDeferred).then(this.run);
    document.addEventListener("click", this.onDeviceReady, false);

},

// NB: onDeviceReady non ha parametri evento
this.onDeviceReady = function() {
    console.log("deviceReady");
    this.deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
},

this.run = function() {
    console.log("main");
}

}

app = new App();
app.init();
```

When I click, I receive

> TypeError: this.deviceReadyDeferred is undefined

Why?

- I don't receive a '$' is undefined, so jQuery is running fine.
- I'm running jQuery 1.9.1 on FF 19.0.2 on Win 7

How to use deferred into a javascript object? How to init and reuse it ?

EDIT:

this code is working.
All the problem was in my misuse of `this`. I'm newbie at OOP with javascript.

```
function App() {

    var self = this;

    this.deviceReadyDeferred = new $.Deferred();

    this.init = function() {
        console.log ("Run");
        $.when(self.deviceReadyDeferred).then(self.run);
        $(document).on("click", self.onClick);

    },

    this.onClick = function() {
        console.log("deviceReady");
        self.deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
    },

    this.run = function() {
        console.log("main");
    }

}

app = new App();
app.init();
```

Comment: You're using jQuery and its Deferred correctly. You're having trouble with the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: `this` inside of `this.onDeviceReady = function() {` is not the same as `this` outside of it.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker You probably didn't click the document to trigger the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.init = function() {
    console.log ("Run");
    var self = this;
    $.when(this.deviceReadyDeferred).then(self.run);
    document.addEventListener("click", self.onDeviceReady, false);

},
```

Comment: Yes ! I edited my question with a copy/pasted already tested version. Tested on FF 19

Comment: Really? Please tell me what kind of error? I posted a working version of the code. Just tested again and working

Comment: I think @bfavaretto is alluding to the fact that IE<=8 didn't implement `addEventListener`. As you are already using jQuery, then it would be more normal to use `$(document).on('click', self.onDeviceReady)`, which handles cross-browser differences.

Comment: @realtebo Actually, I was expecting you get the same "this.deviceReadyDeferred is undefined" when you click the document. If you only change what this answer suggests, you should still see that error. However I see from your update that you changed more, you defined `self` in a higher scope and also replaced `this` with `self` in `onDeviceReady`. That's why it's working.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot See the above comment.

Answer (score 3):

`this` inside of

```
this.onDeviceReady = function() {
    ...
}
```

is not the same as `this` outside of it. jQuery has a built-in way around this by passing data into the event handler.

```
function App() {

    this.deviceReadyDeferred = new $.Deferred();

    this.init = function () {
        console.log("Run");
        $.when(this.deviceReadyDeferred).then(this.run);
        $(document).on("click", { App: this }, this.onDeviceReady);
    },

    // NB: onDeviceReady non ha parametri evento
    this.onDeviceReady = function (e) {
        console.log("deviceReady");
        e.data.App.deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
    },

    this.run = function () {
        console.log("main");
    }

}

app = new App();
app.init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/17/

Or, even easier if you don't have to support IE8, use the native method (note the `.bind(this)`):

```
function App() {

    this.deviceReadyDeferred = new $.Deferred();

    this.init = function () {
        console.log("Run");
        $.when(this.deviceReadyDeferred).then(this.run);
        document.addEventListener("click", this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    },

    // NB: onDeviceReady non ha parametri evento
    this.onDeviceReady = function () {
        console.log("deviceReady");
        this.deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
    },

    this.run = function () {
        console.log("main");
    }

}

app = new App();
app.init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/18/

Answer (score 2):

Other answers already explained the cause, it's the value of `this` inside the callback. One of the ways to solve it is by creating a new function bound to a particular `this` value:

```
document.addEventListener("click", this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
```

Requires a [shim to `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) if not available natively.

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin B says, `this` is `document` inside your `click` handler, because you bound to that event on `document` in the first place.

A simple way to work around this situation is to use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
document.addEventListener("click", $.proxy(this.onDeviceReady, this), false);
```

Comment: I'm using addEventListener because later this code will be part of phoneGap 2.5 android app and it's an already working code !

Comment: +1, $.proxy is better than my bind, since it comes for free with jQuery.